# How do I group lat-lon pairings in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
lon        lat
-77.487    39.044
-77.487    39.044
-122.031   37.354
-77.487    39.044
```

I want to group these lon-lat pairings with a resulting count, like so:

```
lon        lat      count
-77.487    39.044   3
-122.031   37.354   1
```

How can I do this? The `group()` function only appears to allow for grouping by one column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`groupby.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and rename the column created followed by `reset_index` to get back the desired `dataframe`.

```
print(df.groupby(['lon', 'lat']).size().rename('count').reset_index())

       lon     lat  count
0 -122.031  37.354      1
1  -77.487  39.044      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the documentation from the following link

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

```
df_data=df_data.groupby(['lon','lat']).size()
print df_data
```

Comment: You may want `.size()` instead of `.count()`, since you're looking for the size of each group (and not the number of non-missing values in each group)

Comment: This returns the lons and lats as row names instead of as row values

Comment: @DannyDavidLeybzon: This will return a DataFrame with the grouped columns (`lat` and `lon`) as an index. If you want those to be column names instead, try `df_data.groupby(['lon', 'lat']).size().reset_index()`

Comment: @danpelota thanks for pointing it. I just updated the answer to check the size instead of count